# Localize constants not updating properly even after relaunch app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization, nslocalizedstring

I have app level language change option (English & Greek) in my app settings irrespective of device language.

App default language is English.

When I change the app language into Greek and re-launch the app **some of the strings** are not changing into Greek, but when I do the same in English it is working fine. When I re-launch the twice like that all words are changing into the Greek, but not in single re-launch.

How to resolve this language change issue?

We are using RKLocalization from GitHub.

Comment: In my case I have replaced the file name with default name `Localizable.strings`. Now it is working fine.In my project so many pods with language changes, so it is not reloading immediately, after second time reopening the app then it's working. So I have replaced with default file name `Localizable.strings`.